# showexpl not showing caption of a lstlisting within

Tags: listings, showexpl

How can I make the `LTXexample` environment to show the caption (like it does with other environments) of a `lstlisting` that is inside it.

Consider the following code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{showexpl}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

% This lstlisting has its own caption
\begin{lstlisting}[language=C++,caption={Caption of lstlisting}]
#include<iostream>

int main{
  std::cout << "Hello LaTeX\n";
}
\end{lstlisting}

% The lstlisting caption is not shown here
\begin{LTXexample}[pos=b,rframe={},caption={Caption of LTXexample}]
\begin{lstlisting}[language=C++,caption={Caption of lstlisting}]
#include<iostream>

int main{
  std::cout << "Hello LaTeX\n";
}
\end{lstlisting}
\end{LTXexample}

\end{document}
```

As you can see in the image below, when showing the example, the caption of the `lstlisting` within the `LTXexample` doesn't has a caption. I think it may be because the implementation of that environment depends on an `lstlisting`. So, how can I make it to display such caption properly?

Moreover, note that the `label` within the `lstlisting` environment is also ignored.

[image]

Comment: When I try to compile this code I get an error: `! Undefined control sequence.
 ...rrmessage  LaTeX Error: No counter '\@captype
                                                  ' defined.`. Can someone reproduce this? And maybe tell me how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

```
\def\xstrut{\protect\rule[-2ex]{0pt}{2ex}}

% The lstlisting caption is not shown here
\begin{LTXexample}[pos=b,rframe={},caption={Caption of LTXexample\xstrut}]
\begin{lstlisting}[language=C++,caption={Caption of lstlisting}]
#include<iostream>

int main{
  std::cout << "Hello LaTeX\n";
}
\end{lstlisting}
\end{LTXexample}
```

[image]

Comment: But if you see carefully, the second frame doesn't have a caption. It needs a caption that says "Listing 3: Caption of lstlisting".

Comment: Ah I see. Missed that point.